# What is the preferred datatype for storing alphanumeric (Like pancardid,voterid) in sql server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Can you tell me the way for storing alphanumeric in sqlserver? In front i am 
  using c#. So, which datatypes are best for storing alphanumerics (like 
  pancard number,voter number and so on).

And also tell me the equivalent datatype in c#?

I know if we use varchar in sql then the equivalent datatype in c# is string.

For Storing this type of data which datatype are prefered?

Thanks

Comment: [Data Types (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) - [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Yeah..i saw this one can u tell me the best for those?

Comment: You can use string with a Maxlength attribute

Answer (score 1):

for data like yours and similar kinds like mobile number, school identifier etc, your best choice is to use varchar in SQL (nvarchar if you are using any Unicode characters) and in the C# world, use string.

This is not bad at all even if you may feel so, considering that other datatypes have specific purpose behind like byte/int for storing numeric values, date/datetime for storing date and date-time values or Point for storing geographic points.

so to conclude:
SQL server: use varchar or nvarchar
C#: use string.

Comment: I'd even say, in C# - use a custom type that can be converted to string for storage purposes...

Comment: Thanks for your answers